# Return copied and multiplied list

Tags: c#, .net

I want to return a copied version of a given list, in which every element is multiplied by a scalar.

```
...
int attenuation = 3;
return new List<double>(VoltsPerDivX1.Select(x => x*attenuation));
```

`VoltsPerDivX1` is an existing list of type `List<double>`. Is that the right way or are there better ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is slightly more idiomatic:

```
return VoltsPerDivX1.Select(x => x * attenuation).ToList();
```

It also behaves well if your `Select(...)` call emits an anonymous type. In your example, you have to be able to express the type of the list for the constructor call. If you were to do something like:

```
return VoltsPerDivX1
    .Select(x => new { original = x, attenuated =  x * attenuation })
    .ToList();
```

the parameter type of the list can't be expressed since the type is anonymous. It's probably a good habit (if you absolutely need to force evaluation of an `IEnumerable`, and do make sure to ask that question) to use `.ToList()`. There's also `.ToArray()`.